# How do I fix CRUD operation in React+NodeJS(Express)+MySql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, express

I have setup React(Frontend) and NodejsExpress with MySql DB as backend. I am using material Table(client-side) to show data from MysQL server and Perform CRUD Operation. Below is my Backend code i.e

**server.js**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const validator = require('validator');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'Admin123',
    database: 'test_db',
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database: ' + err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the database');
        startServer();
    }
});

function startServer() {
    app.post('/api/register', (req, res) => {
        const { name, emailId, password } = req.body;

        // Validate the email address
        if (!validator.isEmail(emailId)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid email address' });
        }

// API endpoint to get all users
    app.get('/api/darta', (req, res) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM darta', (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error fetching users: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error fetching users');
            } else {
                res.json(results);
            }
        });
    });

    // API endpoint to create a new user
    app.post('/api/darta', (req, res) => {
        const newUser = req.body;
        // Insert the new darta record into the database without an ID

        db.query('INSERT INTO darta SET ?', newUser, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error creating a user: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error creating a user');
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'User created' });
            }
           });
    });

    // API endpoint to update an existing user
    app.put('/api/darta/:id', (req, res) => {
        const userId = req.params.id;
        const updatedUser = req.body;
        db.query('UPDATE darta SET ? WHERE id = ?', [updatedUser, userId], (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error updating user: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error updating user');
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'User updated' });
            }
        });
    });

    // API endpoint to delete a user
    app.delete('/api/darta/:id', (req, res) => {
        const userId = req.params.id;
        db.query('DELETE FROM darta WHERE id = ?', userId, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error deleting user: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error deleting user');
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'User deleted' });
            }
        });
    });
```

And Below is my Client code i.e React code...

**darta.js (React)-Material Table V2 Used**

```
const Darta = () => {
    const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState({});
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/darta') // Replace with your actual API endpoint
            .then((response) => {
                setTableData(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
            });
    }, []);

    const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                accessorKey: 'id',
                header: 'Id',
                enableEditing: false,
                size: 80,
                hiddenOnInsert: true,
            },
            {
                accessorKey: 'firstName',
                header: 'First Name',
                muiEditTextFieldProps: {
                    type: 'text',
                    required: true,
                    error: !!validationErrors?.firstName,
                    helperText: validationErrors?.firstName,
                    onFocus: () =>
                        setValidationErrors({
                            ...validationErrors,
                            firstName: undefined,
                        }),
                },
            },
            {
                accessorKey: 'lastName',
                header: 'Last Name',
                muiEditTextFieldProps: {
                    type: 'text',
                    required: true,
                    error: !!validationErrors?.lastName,
                    helperText: validationErrors?.lastName,
                    onFocus: () =>
                        setValidationErrors({
                            ...validationErrors,
                            lastName: undefined,
                        }),
                },
            },
            {
                accessorKey: 'email',
                header: 'Email',
                muiEditTextFieldProps: {
                    type: 'email',
                    required: true,
                    error: !!validationErrors?.email,
                    helperText: validationErrors?.email,
                    onFocus: () =>
                        setValidationErrors({
                            ...validationErrors,
                            email: undefined,
                        }),
                },
            },
            {
                accessorKey: 'state',
                header: 'State',
                editVariant: 'select',
                editSelectOptions: ['CA', 'NY', 'TX', 'NJ'], // Replace with your state options
                muiEditTextFieldProps: {
                    select: true,
                    error: !!validationErrors?.state,
                    helperText: validationErrors?.state,
                },
            },
            {
                accessorKey: 'remarks',
                header: 'Remarks',
                muiEditTextFieldProps: {
                    type: 'text',
                    required: false,
                    error: !!validationErrors?.remarks,
                    helperText: validationErrors?.remarks,
                    onFocus: () =>
                        setValidationErrors({
                            ...validationErrors,
                            remarks: undefined,
                        }),
                },
            },
        ],
        [validationErrors]
    );


    const { mutateAsync: createUser, isPending: isCreatingUser } = useCreateUser();
    const {
        data: fetchedUsers = [],
        isError: isLoadingUsersError,
        isFetching: isFetchingUsers,
        isLoading: isLoadingUsers,
    } = useGetUsers();
    const { mutateAsync: updateUser, isPending: isUpdatingUser } = useUpdateUser();
    const { mutateAsync: deleteUser, isPending: isDeletingUser } = useDeleteUser();

    const handleCreateUser = async ({ values, table }) => {
        const newValidationErrors = validateUser(values);
        if (Object.values(newValidationErrors).some((error) => error)) {
            setValidationErrors(newValidationErrors);
            return;
        }
        setValidationErrors({});
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/darta', values) // Replace with your actual API endpoint
            .then((response) => {
                setTableData([...tableData, response.data]);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error creating a user: ', error);
            });
        table.setCreatingRow(null);
    };

    const handleSaveUser = async ({ values, table }) => {
        const newValidationErrors = validateUser(values);
        if (Object.values(newValidationErrors).some((error) => error)) {
            setValidationErrors(newValidationErrors);
            return;
        }
        setValidationErrors({});
        Axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/darta/' + values.id, values) // Replace with your actual API endpoint
            .then((response) => {
                const updatedUser = response.data;
                const updatedTableData = tableData.map((user) =>
                    user.id === updatedUser.id ? updatedUser : user
                );
                setTableData(updatedTableData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error updating a user: ', error);
            });
        table.setEditingRow(null);
    };

    const openDeleteConfirmModal = (row) => {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')) {
            Axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/darta/' + row.original.id) // Replace with your actual API endpoint
                .then(() => {
                    const updatedTableData = tableData.filter(
                        (user) => user.id !== row.original.id
                    );
                    setTableData(updatedTableData);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error deleting a user: ', error);
                });
        }
    };

    const table = useMaterialReactTable({
        columns,
        data: fetchedUsers,
        createDisplayMode: 'modal',
        editDisplayMode: 'modal',
        enableEditing: true,
        initialState: { columnVisibility: { id: false } },
        getRowId: (row) => row.id,
        muiToolbarAlertBannerProps: isLoadingUsersError
            ? {
                color: 'error',
                children: 'Error loading data',
            }
            : undefined,
        muiTableContainerProps: {
            sx: {
                minHeight: '500px',
            },
        },
        onCreatingRowCancel: () => setValidationErrors({}),
        onCreatingRowSave: handleCreateUser,
        onEditingRowCancel: () => setValidationErrors({}),
        onEditingRowSave: handleSaveUser,
        renderCreateRowDialogContent: ({ table, row, internalEditComponents }) => (
            <>
                <DialogTitle variant="h3">Create New User</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '1rem' }}>


                    {internalEditComponents}
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <MRT_EditActionButtons variant="text" table={table} row={row} />
                </DialogActions>
            </>
        ),


        renderEditRowDialogContent: ({ table, row, internalEditComponents }) => (
            <>
                <DialogTitle variant="h3">Edit User</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '1.5rem' }}>
                    {internalEditComponents}
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <MRT_EditActionButtons variant="text" table={table} row={row} />
                </DialogActions>
            </>
        ),
        renderRowActions: ({ row, table }) => (
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1rem' }}>
                <Tooltip title="Edit">
                    <IconButton onClick={() => table.setEditingRow(row)}>
                        <EditIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
                <Tooltip title="Delete">
                    <IconButton color="error" onClick={() => openDeleteConfirmModal(row)}>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            </Box>
        ),
        renderTopToolbarCustomActions: ({ table }) => (
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                    table.setCreatingRow(true);
                }}
            >
                New User
            </Button>
        ),
        state: {
            isLoading: isLoadingUsers,
            isSaving: isCreatingUser || isUpdatingUser || isDeletingUser,
            showAlertBanner: isLoadingUsersError,
            showProgressBars: isFetchingUsers,
        },
    });

    return <MaterialReactTable table={table} />;
};

function useCreateUser() {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const { mutate: createUser } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async (user) => {
            // Create the new user record in the database without an ID
            const response = await Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/darta', user);

            // Get the new user object from the response
            const newUser = response.data;

            // Update the state with the new user object
            queryClient.setQueryData(['users'], (prevUsers) => [
                ...prevUsers,
                {
                    ...newUser,
                },
            ]);
        },
        onMutate: (newUserInfo) => {
            // Don't update the state here, because the new user record doesn't have an ID yet
        },
    });

    return { createUser };
}


function useUpdateUser() {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: async (user) => {
            const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/darta/' + user.id, user); // Replace with your actual API endpoint
            return response.data;
        },
        onMutate: (newUserInfo) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(['users'], (prevUsers) =>
                prevUsers?.map((prevUser) =>
                    prevUser.id === newUserInfo.id ? newUserInfo : prevUser
                )
            );
        },
    });
}

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const DartaWithProviders = () => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Darta />
    </QueryClientProvider>
);

}
```

What I tried is...

The server is working fine, the GET, PUT and DELETE operations are working fine but POST method data is not posting data to database. The error I got is,

*Error creating a user: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `mun_mis`.`darta`.`id` at row 1*

But, If I manually enter ID from Client user Form. The POST isalso working.

What is expected is, the id should be automatically created from database when new data is inserted, not manually enter from clientside( client form).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.query('INSERT INTO darta SET ?', newUser, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error creating a user: ' + err);
                res.status(500).send('Error creating a user');
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'User created' });
            }
           });
```

This specific snippet seems to be wrong. To insert into a table, the syntax is like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3 , ..., columnN) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ..., valueN);
```

Comment: The column id is already INT and auto_increament  and primary key

Comment: Then it should work fine. You are using MYSQL, right?

Comment: Yes I'm using MYSQL. It's not working.

Comment: Hi @PrakashBhandari, I have updated my answer. Could you please check it?